# HttpListenerException in local cluster

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting, httplistener, azure-service-fabric

I have two seperate (two seperate visual studio solutions) service fabric applications. Both are simple web api services from that example:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/

I deployed the my first example in the local cluster and it was running. Then I deployed the second (similar) example on the same local cluster and I got the following exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       bei Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
       bei Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
       bei Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(String url, Action`1 startup)
       bei WebApi.Service.OwinCommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\...\WebApi.Service\OwinCommunicationListener.cs:Zeile 40.
       bei Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceBase.<OpenCommunicationListenersAsync>d__a.MoveNext()
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=183
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Fehler beim Abhören von Präfix http://+:80/webapp/, da es mit einer vorhandenen Registrierung auf dem Computer in Konflikt steht.
       NativeErrorCode=183
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            bei System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
            bei System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
            bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
            bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, IDictionary`2 properties)
       InnerException:
```

After that, I removed the local cluster and create a new one. Then I just deployed the second application and it is still not running. I also restarted my computer, but still doesn't working. Then I tried again the first application and it was running.

I don't know what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem for my own.

For whatever reasons, the application parameters were missing:

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/WebApplication" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="WebApiService_InstanceCount" Value="1" />
   </Parameters>
</Application>
```

Comment: My German is a little rusty, but I've seen this exception enough times to tell you why adding that parameter fixed the problem. It was creating multiple instances of the service on the same machine, which means you had multiple processes all fighting over the same port. Adding that parameter limited the number of instances to 1.